# Drawing parameters in OpenStreetMap URL

Tags: url, openstreetmap

I've learnt that one can add annotation on maps on OpenStreetMap by adding

1. box=yes&bbox=`lon1`,`lat1`,`lon2`,`lat2` to draw a rectangle and
2. mlon=`lon`&mlat=`lat` to add a marker

e.g.

```
 http://openstreetmap.org/?box=yes&bbox=-1%2C51%2C1%2C52&mlon=0&mlat=52
```

What other drawing parameters (most importantly, text, if possible) can one add to OpenStreetMap URLs? It must be a simple URL I can email to someone, so no using APIs or running my own webserver.

Answer (score 2):

I think the ones you mention pretty much cover what is available actually - the only other ones are the `node`, `way` and `relation` parameters for overlaying specific OpenStreetMap objects on the map.

I would add though that most of these parameters are considered internal implementation details for use by the OpenStreetMap site itself and you shouldn't really be relying on them for use in other places.

The only real exception to that is the `mlat` and `mlon` parameters as they are used by the embedded map export tool to overlay a marker so it is unlikely we would remove those.